# convert datatypes for respective columns as per the dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a pysaprk dataframe with 100 cols:

```
df1=[(col1,string),(col2,double),(col3,bigint),..so on]
```

I have another pyspark dataframe df2 with same col count and col names but different datatypes.

```
df2=[(col1,bigint),(col2,double),(col3,string),..so on]
```

how do i make the dataypes of all the cols in df2 same as ones present in the dataframe df1 for their respective cols?

It should happen iteratively and if the datatypes match then it should not change

Answer (score 0):

If as you said the *column* names match and columns count match, then you can simply loop in the `schema` of *df1* and *cast* the columns to `dataTypes` of *df1*

```
df2 = df2.select([F.col(c.name).cast(c.dataType) for c in df1.schema])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cast` function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

# get schema for each DF
df1_schema=df1.dtypes
df2_schema=df2.dtypes

# iterate through cols to cast columns which differ in type
for (c1, d1), (c2,d2) in zip(df1_schema, df2_schema):
    # check if datatypes are the same, otherwise cast
    if d1!=d2:
        df2=df2.withColumn(c2, f.col(c2).cast(d2))
```